# C++ exit code 3221225725, Karatsuba multiplication recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

The Karatsuba multiplication algorithm implementation does not output any result and exits with code=3221225725.

Here is the message displayed on the terminal:

```
[Running] cd "d:\algorithms_cpp\" && g++ karatsube_mul.cpp -o karatsube_mul && "d:\algorithms_cpp\"karatsube_mul

[Done] exited with code=3221225725 in 1.941 seconds
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string kara_mul(string n, string m)
{
    int len_n = n.size();
    int len_m = m.size();
    if (len_n == 1 && len_m == 1)
    {
        return to_string((stol(n) * stol(m)));
    }
    string a = n.substr(0, len_n / 2);
    string b = n.substr(len_n / 2);
    string c = m.substr(0, len_m / 2);
    string d = m.substr(len_m / 2);

    string p1 = kara_mul(a, c);
    string p2 = kara_mul(b, d);
    string p3 = to_string((stol(kara_mul(a + b, c + d)) - stol(p1) - stol(p2)));

    return to_string((stol(p1 + string(len_n, '0')) + stol(p2) + stol(p3 + string(len_n / 2, '0'))));
}

int main()
{
    cout << kara_mul("15", "12") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And after fixing this I would also like to know how to multiply two 664 digit integers using this technique.

Comment: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and even more important, about [including `bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)...

Comment: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225725](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225725) says you have a stack overflow

Comment: And as soon as you rely on `stol` or variants of you're bound to fail due to overflow. Why would anyone encode in strings? Because numbers won't fit into fixed-size integers...

Comment: `operator+` for `std::string`s does just a concatenation, so `kara_mul(a + b, c + d)` is just the same as `kara_mul(n, m)` – endless (well, until you run out of stack at least) recursion...

Comment: You will have to do the additions based on strings yourself. But then consider a simple case of `67 * 89` – you need to multiply 7 and 9, giving a final digit of 3 – unfortunately the 6 is a *carry*, you need to add it to the result of 7*8 + 6*9, so you get 116, which again gives a carry of 11 – so result of 59, concatenated previous remainders of 6 and 3 gives "59"+"6"+"3" = "5963".

Comment: Yet a minor issue: You do not modify the strings being passed as arguments – thus you should accept them as const reference, i.e. `std::string const& n, std::string const& m`, otherwise you create unnecessary copies of – with every recursive call!

Comment: Learn to use a debugger! Using that, you could have stepped through the code and inspected its state at any point in time and you would have found the problem yourself quickly. Also, sometimes it's good to output intermediate results to get an idea of what's going on. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I suggest to select *one* accessible description of [Karatsuba's multiplication algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Algorithm), try to implement it faithfully - and identify it where wanting to discuss implementation. There is at least one major misunderstanding about the algorithm besides `std::string operator+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- The exception you got is caused by infinite recursion at this call:

  ```
  kara_mul(a + b, c + d)
  ```

  As these variables are strings, the `+` is a string concatenation. This means these arguments evaluate to
  `n` and `m`, which were the arguments to the current execution of the function.

  The correct algorithm would perform a numerical addition here, for which you need to provide an implementation (adding two string representations of potentially very long integers)
- `if (len_n == 1 && len_m == 1)` detects the base case, but the base case should kick in when *either* of these sizes is 1, not necessary *both*. So this should be an `||` operator, or should be written as two separate `if` statements.
- The input strings should be split such that `b` and `d` are equal in size. This is not what your code does. Note how the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Implementation) stresses this point:

  > The second argument of the split_at function specifies the number of digits to extract from the *right*
- `stol` should never be called on strings that could potentially be too long for conversion to `long`. So for example, `stol(p1)` is not safe, as `p1` could have 20 or more digits.
- As a consequence of the previous point, you'll need to implement functions that add or subtract two string representations of numbers, and also one that can multiply a string representation with a single digit (the base case).

Here is an implementation that corrects these issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 

int digit(std::string n, int i) {
    return i >= n.size() ? 0 : n[n.size() - i - 1] - '0';
}

std::string add(std::string n, std::string m) {
    int len = std::max(n.size(), m.size());
    std::string result;
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int sum = digit(n, i) + digit(m, i) + carry; 
        result += (char) (sum % 10 + '0');
        carry = sum >= 10;
    }
    if (carry) result += '1';
    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

std::string subtract(std::string n, std::string m) {
    int len = n.size();
    if (m.size() > len) throw std::invalid_argument("subtraction overflow");
    if (n == m) return "0";
    std::string result;
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int diff = digit(n, i) - digit(m, i) - carry;
        carry = diff < 0;
        result += (char) (diff + carry * 10 + '0');
    }
    if (carry) throw std::invalid_argument("subtraction overflow");
    result.erase(result.find_last_not_of('0') + 1);
    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

std::string simple_mul(std::string n, int coefficient) {
    if (coefficient < 2) return coefficient ? n : "0";
    std::string result = simple_mul(add(n, n), coefficient / 2);
    return coefficient % 2 ? add(result, n) : result;
}

std::string kara_mul(std::string n, std::string m) {
    int len_n = n.size();
    int len_m = m.size();
    if (len_n == 1) return simple_mul(m, digit(n, 0));
    if (len_m == 1) return simple_mul(n, digit(m, 0));
    int len_min2 = std::min(len_n, len_m) / 2; 
    std::string a = n.substr(0, len_n - len_min2);
    std::string b = n.substr(len_n - len_min2);
    std::string c = m.substr(0, len_m - len_min2);
    std::string d = m.substr(len_m - len_min2);

    std::string p1 = kara_mul(a, c);
    std::string p2 = kara_mul(b, d);
    std::string p3 = subtract(kara_mul(add(a, b), add(c, d)), add(p1, p2));
    return add(add(p1 + std::string(len_min2*2, '0'), p2), p3 + std::string(len_min2, '0'));
}
```